# How to SUM Row values and save the result in a new Total Column?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I need to calculate the sum of stock from some rows, the same product exist for different companies, so I need to calculate the SUM/Total of all products, per product name, this is the result that I want to achieve:

```
ID | Name     | Company | Stock | Total Stock
1  | Product1 | Company1| 10    | 30
2  | Product1 | Company2| 10    | 30
3  | Product1 | Company2| 10    | 30
4  | Product2 | Company1| 10    | 15
5  | Product2 | Company2| 5     | 15
6  | Product3 | Company2| 5     | 5
7  | Product4 | Company1| 6     | 10
8  | Product4 | Company2| 4     | 10
```

Etc...
The Total Stock is the sum of **Select SUM(Stock) From Product Where Name="Product1"** 
How can I save this result ? Should I use a Trigger Or a Procedure? I have basic knowledge of SQL

This needs to run every 30 minutes or every time a row is updated.

The product table has around 40.000 Products.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  a.*, b.totalStock
FROM    tableName a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT Name, SUM(Stock) totalStock
            FROM tableName
            GROUP BY Name
        ) b on a.name = b.name
-- WHERE a.Name = 'Product1'
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b196a/1)

*PS: you need to use `ID` instead of `Name`.*

Comment: Hi John, thanks for that, that was super quick :)

Can you explain how I can do this operation automaticly, every 30min or if one of the rows is updated?

Comment: @AdamSurfari as you can see, the subquery gets the total number of stocks per name of your product in the table. This is join against the original table for the same product name.

Comment: Is this usable for a 40.000 product table? Or do those inner joins start to cause performance issues?

Comment: stability is not based on just row count, but indexes and other performance metrics.  Use mysql explain to see how the query looks.